# Passing Parameters to a function JSF

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf

Hi guys i need to pass some parameters to an actionListener this is my code

```
<p:dialog id="dialog" header="Acceso Restringido" widgetVar="dlgRegister" modal="true">  
<h:form>  

    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">  
        <h:outputLabel for="username" value="Nombre de Usuario:" />  
        <p:inputText value="#{loginBean.usuario.username}"   
                id="username" required="true" label="username" />  

        <h:outputLabel for="password" value="Contraseña:" />  
        <h:inputSecret value="#{loginBean.usuario.password}"   
                id="password" required="true" label="password" />

        <h:outputLabel for="correo" value="Correo:" />  
        <h:inputSecret value="#{loginBean.usuario.correo}"   
                id="correo" required="true" label="correo" />

        <f:facet name="footer">  
            <p:commandButton id="regButton" value="Registrar" update=":growl"   
                             actionListener="#{loginBean.login(actionEvent)}"   
                oncomplete="handleLoginRequest(xhr, status, args)"/>  
        </f:facet>  
    </h:panelGrid>  

</h:form>
```

well I need to pas svalue="#{loginBean.usuario.username}" example to actionListener="#{loginBean.login(actionEvent,---HERE----)}"

Answer (score 1):

```
actionListener="#{loginBean.login(actionEvent)}"
```

This is not right. There does not exist a managed bean `#{actionEvent}` in the scope at all. JSF will already prepare the real `ActionEvent` argument itself for action listener methods. Just omit it:

```
actionListener="#{loginBean.login}"
```

JSF will implicitly create and pass the right argument.

You can access the username just straight inside the method:

```
public void login(ActionEvent event) {
    System.out.println(usario.getUsername()); // Look, it's already been set by JSF.
}
```

#### See also:

- [Differences between action and actionListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909267/differences-between-action-and-actionlistener/3909382#3909382)

Answer (score 0):

1. The value is setted in loginBean.usario.username already
2. You can set that there just like loginBean.usario.username